# Windows8 - Using localised string in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have got problem with localizing my app. I have got file Resources.resw with string "noResults.Text" in it (it ends with .Text because I use it in xaml for textblock (x:Uid) ) Problem is that I want to use the same string in code behind (C#) How I can access it? I have tried something like this :

```
resourceLoader.GetString("noResults");
resourceLoader.GetString("noResults.Text");
```

But none of this work

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
var loader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
string result = loader.GetString("noResults/text");
```

Note that in your resource, if you are using "noResults.text", do not define another string as "noResults" (no extension).

Comment: Does Microsoft document this anywhere?

Comment: Does this count? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/ae1ccf29-ef09-4de8-a50e-89476983a9ca/windows-8-metro-xaml-localization?forum=winappswithcsharp

Comment: The solution is buried pretty deep in that link. Thanks for this SO answer!

Comment: MS says its not possible?! https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965323.aspx: "The GetString method cannot retrieve resources qualified with a property identifier."